# Android Cardboard Tour

Tags: android, video

I would like to create a tour like the demo of google cardboard palace of Versailles. I'm not much of Android expert. Can you give me some advice on how to do? I tried it with unity but Android does not support movie textures and should I buy a plugin. But I would avoid buying. Is there any example of such a code?

Comment: What sort of resources/guides have you seen already?

Comment: the Android Demo app...and documentation....